# Sequence of yield select() is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have below piece of code which is not working

`let name =. yield select(getName()); // getName is in same folder selector let details= yield select(getDetails()); // getDetails is in different selector of different folder`

.

When trying to call the two different yield in my generator functions,only first yield is getting triggered and second yield is not getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but I suspect the issue is in that you are calling your selectors instead of passing them as reference. Try this:

```
let name = yield select(getName);
let details = yield select(getDetails);
```